# Return value from BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I'm trying to make the app `detect when a new SMS is received`.
For doing this I registered `programatically a new BroadcastReceiver`, where I process the incoming **SMSs** and then it should return a value, that the fragment that registered the **BroadcastReceiver should retrieve**.
`I can't get to retrieve the value returned from the BroadcastReceiver`. I've seen other StackOverflow questions about returning values to Activities, but they always end up creating a new Activity. I don't want that. **`I want to get the value in the same place where I registered the BroadcastReceiver`**. How should I do this?
This is the code from the BroadcastReceiver:

```
public class RegisterSms extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        // stuff...
        this.setResultData("data to return");

    }
}
```

In the fragment I'm doing this:

```
BroadcastReceiver smsReceiver = new RegisterSms();
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
this.getContext().registerReceiver(smsReceiver, filter);
// here I should be receiving the data sent by the BroadcastReceiver
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create your broadcast receiver as an anonymous inner class.

```
private BroadcastReceiver smsReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            //here you can parse intent and get sms fields.
        }
    };
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
this.getContext().registerReceiver(smsReceiver, filter);
```

Comment: Anonymous inner class is the only way?